# No Info pop-up in Chrome timeline

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

As per the documentation the Chrome timeline should show a pop-up with info about recorded events. This pop-up is not showing in my Chrome 46 on Linux XFCE nor on my Chrome Canary on Windows 10.

Was that removed? Did they put this information somewhere else?

I can't even see the description of warning signs next to certain records.
The thing I am most interested in is the reason for certain style recalculations that should show up in these pop-ups.

That is what I am talking about:
[image: Pop-up with timeline info]

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome 47 all information displayed on the pop-up above can be found in the Summary view below the Records section:

[image]